# Creating an installer with C# application project,mysql server and ability to automatic restore database to MySQL server

Tags: c#, mysql, database, installation

I developed a `C#.NET` desktop application that uses MySQL as a back-end. What I want is that when user installs the application, the MySQL server should automatically installed and username and password are automatically set and the database is restored from a SQL Dump file automatically by the installer. I am using setup project in visual studio to create installer. Is it possible to perform this operation in an installer?? If yes then please tell how to perform these operations??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't unless your database server is MSSQL. Better create a separate installation between your application and the database server.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue like This

1. tack all  the Backup of the MySql Data base
2. Created Console Utility which store the database in console Application
3. By Using Heat.exe added the Sql File And .Exe file to the Project (Wix)
4. Use the Custom Action Call the Exe Which Store the Database Backup
5. Delete the Exe and Sql File from the Install location